# How do I export custom type names from a C++ OCX module?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ocx

I'm frequently using OCX controls with VB6 and some export their own type names for enumeration types, such as here:

[image: afioShow]

`show` is actually a `Long` (signed 32 bit number), but because only the values 0–4 are allowed as parameters for this function, the OCX defines `_afioShow` as an enumeration from 0 to 4. This also means that wherever a value of this type is needed, the VB6 IDE automatically shows a dropdown list with the enumeration members (`showMinimized`, `showMaximized` and so on).

I would like to do something similar in an OCX module that I am writing. How can I define and export such a type? I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a typedef for the enum in your IDL.  A random example:

```
typedef enum {
  digitOne=1,
  digitTwo=2
} EnumDigits;

[
  object,
  uuid(5F3D3E00-0F66-4199-B548-654A9174552B),
  dual,
  pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IHandleDigits : IDispatch {
  [id(0),  propget] HRESULT Digit([out,retval] EnumDigits* retval);
}
```